# How to check Items in listview in android?

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` in my app which is on create execute Url that fetches 5 names from a server and *loadmore* `Button` added in `ListView`. What I want when 5 names from server is shown to user, if user clicks on *loadmore* button, first check if items in `ListView` contain 5, then onClick *loadmore*, request to server for 5 more. How do I do that?

Here is my code:-

```
btnLoadMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            m_n_DefaultRecordCount = 5;// increment of record count by 5 on next load data
            m_n_DeafalutLastCount = m_n_DeafalutLastCount + 5;// same here.....as above

            sz_RecordCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DefaultRecordCount);// convert int value to string
            sz_LastCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DeafalutLastCount);// convert int value to string /////
            new DealNext().execute(m_DealListingURL);// POST DATA TO SERVER TO LOAD MORE DATA......
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you checked endless scroll listview android https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews. You don't need a load more button

Comment: you need to do some pagination

Comment: yes you don't need view more button. you can set listview scroll listener and when all items are scrolled you can fetch more data.

Comment: try this ref: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/

Answer (score 2):

1- place button below ListView .

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_more"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>
    <Button
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/btn_more"
        android:text="LoadMore"
        android:onClick="loadMore"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

2- set onclick to button.

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wifi);

}
public void loadMore(View view){
    //send request to server
    // or load data where you want
}
```

3- send request to server or load data where you want.

4- add new 5 records into ArrayList

```
List<String list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("abc");
list.add("abc");
list.add("abc");
list.add("abc");
list.add("abc");
```

5- Notifiy ado

```
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```